# How do I make a "changing" attribute in python? [Please Close]

Tags: python, oop

(EDITED) I am trying to make an object that would have an attribute, if you do for example object.add1 it would add one to the attribute so if you call object.attribute again it would return that +1.

```
object.attribute
>>> 1
object.add1
>>>
object.attribute
>>> 2
```

I first tried a simple approach:

```
self.attribute = str(value + 1)
```

Did not work.

I then tried an approach using the setattr() function.

Looked something like this:

```
class add1:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.status = val
        self.change = setattr(self, str(val), str(val + 1))
```

Also did not work. I cannot find any resources online, so how would I get this to work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm failing to understand what you want, and why.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this? Maybe you could share your actual use-case, and we may be able to suggest a more idiomatic, Pythonic solution. It seems like you want to define a class with an `add` method.

Comment: Why not simply `object.add(1)` ??

Comment: Try defining methods!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works per your question, however there is surely a better way of achieving what you are trying to do - although it is hard to see what you are trying to achieve.

```
>>> class adder():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = 1
    @property
    def add1(self):
        self.attribute += 1

>>> object = adder()
>>> object.attribute
1
>>> object.add1
>>> object.attribute
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a *method*:

```py
class AddExample:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val


    def add1(self):
        self.value += 1
```

```py
example = AddExample(1)
print(example.value)  # prints 1
example.add1()
print(example.value)  # prints 2
```

Further reading: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes